# Nginx Reverse Proxy settings

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, phpredis

I am in the process of setting up a server configuration which consists of

- A front end server running Nginx.  Call it `example.com`
- Another server, also running Nginx, (on the same network and accessible via an internal IP, say `10.118.10.9`) which runs - amongst other things - phpRedisAdmin.
- The front end server has a reverse proxy configuration that goes like this

  location ^~ /admin/ {
  proxy_pass https://10.118.0.9:8085/;
  }

Now when I browse to `https://example.com/admin/redisadmin/index.php'

The Memcache Admin page turns up just right.  An examination of console logs shows now errors. I then proceed to click the **Add Another Key** link which brings up the phpMemcachedAdmin edit form.  When I examine the code for this form I see

```
<form action="/redisadmin/edit.php?s=0" method="post">
```

Now if I enter a key name, a value and click on the Add button in the form the browser attempts to post to

```
https://example.com/redisadmin/edit.php?s=0
```

which promptly throws up a 404 since the action URL for the form should in fact have been

```
<form action="/admin/redisadmin/edit.php?s=0" method="post">
```

Somewhere along the way the `/admin` bit got lopped off.  I suspect that this is down to invalid Nginx reverse proxy settings.  However, I am a novice when it comes to this so I have no idea how I should correct the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have checked the page of redis admin and found it reads the request URI from server side, which means it will include the leading slash '/' in the URL for the post form:

```
<form action="<?php echo format_html($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>" method="post">
```

You have the remove the leading slash in php so you can post to correct address when access via reverse proxy. However, as a workaround, you can rewrite the URL in nginx to fix it.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/redisadmin/(.*)$ /admin/redisadmin/$1 last;
```

Add the above rewrite rule to your setting in '/' seciton, see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As @Johnnie Zhang has pointed out the root of the issue here was the leading / which resulted in the post action being treated as an absolute path.  However, after a bit of investigation I have concluded that although phpredisadmin is an excellent all-round option when used as a standalone Redis web GUI it is liable to be pose too many problems when used via a reverse proxy.